# Issue with formatting json array in new file

Tags: json

After creating a new file for json, I am needing to create two arrays, when creating the first one, an error popped up where it doesn't want to accept type1:[ as the array's start.

Tried using a validator, inside, I switched to a comma after it confirmed the error, that didn't give the desired effect.

```
    {
    "type1":[
        "product1":{

        },
        "product2":{

        },
        "product3":{

        }
    ]
}
```

It threw up an error message when I expected to be able to expand on products and then have the basic system to practice with.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use an array like an object? JSON arrays can only contain an ordered sequence of _values_, not _key:value_ pairs.

Answer (score 0):

```
  {
   "type1":[  
      {  
         "product1":{  

         }
      },
      {  
         "product2":{  

         }
      },
      {  
         "product3":{  

         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Please use this format. your format is invalid. as @kmr said

"JSON arrays cant contain key value pairs"